# how to set checkbox by default true

Tags: html, angularjs

html  :

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedRecord.extendLiveData" >
</div>
```

Js:

```
$scope.selectedRecord.extendLiveData = true;
```

Want to set checkbox by default true . How ? without `ng-checked`, `ng-change`

Comment: Is your checkbox inside an ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `selectedRecord` object with `extendLiveData` field with true value.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('chkboxCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectedRecord = {extendLiveData: true}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="chkboxCtrl">
  
  
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedRecord.extendLiveData">
          <span class="fa fa-check"></span> checkbox checked by default

        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through HTML this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedRecord.extendLiveData" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

just initialize the `$scope.selectedRecord` as object

```
$scope.selectedRecord = {};
$scope.selectedRecord.extendLiveData = true;
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.selectedRecord = {};
$scope.selectedRecord.extendLiveData = true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedRecord.extendLiveData" >  box value {{selectedRecord.extendLiveData}}
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put "checked" in input tag. Like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedRecord.extendLiveData" checked>
```